# Python Wordpress-XMLRPC: ServerConnectionError: <ProtocolError 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: python, wordpress

I am a python newb so please forgive me. I have searched on Google and SA but couldn't find anything. Anyway, I am using the python library [Wordpress XMLRPC](http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html).

`myblog`, `myusername`, and `mypassword` are just placeholders to hide my real website, username and password. When I run the code I use my real data.

My Code:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import *
wp = Client('http://www.myblog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'myusername', 'mypassword')
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/wordpress_bro", line 2, in <module>
    wp = Client('http://www.myblog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'myusername', 'mypassword')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\wordpress_xmlrpc\base.py", line 27, in __init__
    raise ServerConnectionError(repr(e))
ServerConnectionError: <ProtocolError for www.myblog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php: 301 Moved Permanently>
```

When I go to `http://www.myblog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php` in my browser I get:

```
XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.
```

Could somebody please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it was the problem of wordpress.com. If you setup a wordpress installation yourself it will work. Wordpress.com has XMLRPC disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try it adding the "s" to the http string.. something like:

```
wp = Client('https://www.myblog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'myusername', 'mypassword')
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when I used wordpress_xmlrpc. I had a .htaccess file which redirects http traffic to https. This caused the 301 Moved Permanently error.

My "get it working, to solve it better later" solution was to comment out the redirect in my .htaccess file and add it back in when I'm done.